# Spring Application getting shutdown After Period of time Automatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have stated my application then it got shut down after 2 hours automatically and there no logs which tell me the reason.
 Can anyone help me regarding this?
 I didn't hit any rest end point but it gets shutdown automatically.

Please find sample logs below.

> 2018-08-31 17:47:48.099  INFO 18278 --- [main]
>   c.p.c2i.fulfillment.app.Application      : Started Application in
>   8.936 seconds (JVM running for 9.6)
>       2018-08-31 20:01:18.904  INFO 18278 --- [Thread-3] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5ecddf8f:
>   startup date [Fri Aug 31 17:47:40 IST 2018]; root of context
>   hierarchy
>       2018-08-31 20:01:18.907  INFO 18278 --- [Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans on shutdown
>       2018-08-31 20:01:18.909  INFO 18278 --- [Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans
>       
>       2018-08-31 20:01:18.912  INFO 18278 --- [Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>       2018-08-31 20:01:18.913  INFO 18278 --- [Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
>   initiated... 
>       2018-08-31 20:01:18.925  INFO 18278 --- [Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
>   completed.

Comment: see this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12542

Comment: Thanks, Alien for this link but still I am unable to figure it out the solution. :(